# PHP: isset vs is_null - When do I need to use one over another?

Tags: php, isset, isnullorempty

I am trying to comprehend how PHP's `isset()` and `is_null()` functions are different from one another.

I do understand their difference from the manual, but cannot come up with any example of when I absolutely need to use one function over another.

It seems I can use one or the other and it wouldn't matter, except that `isset` doesn't throw a `Notice` error if the reference didn't exist, while `is_null` would.

If I suppress such type of errors, then in terms of functionality these 2 functions would be exactly similar.

Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: My question isn't a duplicate. Please read through the whole question. What I am asking here is that if I suppress "Notice" errors , then in terms of functionality these 2 functions would be exactly similar. I only need people to confirm it or convince me otherwise

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be suppressing errors. 2) These two functions are different as explained in the duplicate answer.

Comment: Suppressing the errors is a test scenario

Comment: Which proves nothing and is completely irrelevant to the functionality of the two functions.

Comment: I haven't set out to prove anything. It is only a means to understand how one is different from another. Like I said before, I do understand the difference between the 2, but given a specific scenario they seem to be the same.

Comment: Suppressing errors is not a realistic test case scenario. I have never heard QA tell devs to make you sure you test functionality at different error reporting levels.

Comment: I am not saying its a test scenario for the people in QA. I am only trying to see if I can replace one function with another in specific scenarios. Please understand that the reason I am doing so is because it makes it easier for me to see the difference. I can say, this is where it behaves similarly and this is where it would behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

`null` means nothing, no value, whereas you use `isset()` say whether a variable `isset`, for example..

```
$var = null;

isset($var); //returns false, checks whether the variable isset, 
             //but it's null so will return false

is_null($var); //Returns true, checks whether the value of variable is null
```

From [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) :

> If a variable has been unset with `unset()`, it will no longer be set.
>   `isset()` will return `FALSE` if testing a variable that has been set to
>   `NULL`.

Going further, we alter the variable value

```
$var = 'hello';
isset($var); //will return true as the variable is no more null
is_null($var); //will return false as variable holds a string now
```

---

*If I suppress such type of errors*

No you shouldn't, always turn on the error reporting, writing bad code won't help you anyways.

Comment: I am trying to understand the functions better. Suppressing the errors is a test scenario. Can you give me one example of when I have to use one over the other.

Comment: When posting a form, you want to check `if(isset($_POST...))` and not `is_null` because the variable can be *set* and pass your logic.

Comment: @user1720897 `is_null()` checks the value of your var, where as `isset()` checks whether a variable isset and is not null